(AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
I am trying to enable object lock option in s3 in AWS.
it seems that this option is not working trough GUI and we should use CLI to enable it for upload objects.
when I try to create an objcet as a sample I get bellow error message:
aws s3api put-object --bucket <my Bucketlist name> --key test-1 --body test-1 --object-lock-mode GOVERNANCE --object-lock-retain-until-date 2025-06-12

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

I also enabled public ACL policy as well as access permssion as the follwing JSON format:
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "ExamplePolicy01",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ExampleStatement01",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:root"
        },
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<my Bucketlist name>",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<my Bucketlist name>/*"
        ]
    }
]

}
anyone faced this issue before?

What do you mean by "this option is not working through GUI"? It's likely that there will be the same underlying problem. I suggest you focus on that first. (I don't think the Bucket Policy you have shown is useful for anything.) Could you confirm that you can upload an object if you do not specify --object-lock-mode? Does the bucket have Versioning and Object Lock activated?

Another thing to check is that you have permission to upload an Object Version. You can test this by uploading an object without the --object-lock-mode part. Then, run the same command again -- this will create another 'version' of the object if you have the correct permissions.
